# Casting Const Void to String Errors

Tags: c, casting

I have this line of code here where I am trying to type cast two void arguments as strings and then use the strcmp function to compare the two:

```
int compareFirstName(const void * p1, const void * p2)
{
  const char **str1, **str2;
  str1 = (char **) &p1;
  str2 = (char **) &p2;
  return strcmp(*str1, *str2);
}
```

However, I keep getting the error,

```
assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
   str1 = (char **) &p1;
        ^
```

I am pretty sure I am casting right, so I do not know what the problem seems to be. Before, I had a segmentation fault error but resolved it and am now stuck here.

EDIT:
This is the struct I am using to compare the first names, IDS, and last names. Turns out I have to convert the void * into Student *, which I am a bit confused about

```
typedef struct
{
  int ID;
  char firstname[NAME_LENGTH] ;
  char lastname[NAME_LENGTH] ;
} Student;
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are using this comparison function for. To me it looks like you want to use it for `qsort` or something similar.

Comment: Yes, it will be used for qsort along with a struct

Comment: Then you *still* don't need double pointers. Just move your `p1` and `p2` into two `Student*` pointers (`s1` and `s2`) and then `return strcmp(s1->firstname, s2->firstname);`. But that's really the answer given by 0___________ (with a minor modification after your edit).

Comment: What is the purpose of this function? Compare specific elements of two given objects or all elements? What would be the use case?

Answer (score 4):

AFTER QUESTION EDIT:

```
int compareFirstName(const void * p1, const void * p2)
{
  const Student *str1, *str2;
  str1 = p1;
  str2 = p2;
  return strcmp(str1 -> firstname, str2 -> lastname);
}

/* the real cars is used here */
int compareFirstName1(const void * p1, const void * p2)
{
  return strcmp(((const Student *)p1) -> firstname, ((const Student *)p2) -> lastname);
}
```

BEFORE EDIT

You are not trying to cast as "strings" only to pointer to pointer to char which has nothing in common with the C strings.

You also do not want to get the reference to the local parameters `p1` and `p2`

You want:

```
int compareFirstName(const void * p1, const void * p2)
{
  const char *str1, *str2;
  str1 = p1;
  str2 = p2;
  return strcmp(str1, str2);
}
```

or just enough

```
int compareFirstName(const void * p1, const void * p2)
{
  return strcmp(p1, p2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the question is slightly different than what it was before, I have decided to post a new answer:

```
int compareFirstName(const void * p1, const void * p2)
{
    const Student *s1, *s2;
    s1 = p1;
    s1 = p2;
    return strcmp(s1->firstname, s2->firstname);
}
```

This is the way to cast the `void *` arguments to the structs that you typedef'ed as `Student`. Then because p1 and p2 are pointers to structs, you need to use `->` to access the members.

Comment: @Cheatah there is no cast here